# Will Delphi Tokyo work with Advantage Database 11x

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I have a set of applications that use Delphi Seattle with Advantage Database 11x components. I have installed Delphi Tokyo and am trying to migrate these applications without also changing the ADS version from 11x. I have seen articles with workarounds on how to do this using ADS 12x, but nothing for 11x. I tried the techniques in the articles using the Seattle version, but get a lot of compiler errors of various sorts that are not documented in the articles.  Does anyone know if it is possible to do this, and if so, would you mind sharing how?  Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For the most part, you just have to update the ADS.Inc file to include the proper compiler version. (The way they've done it is really convoluted, so it typically takes a lot of concentration and a couple of efforts to get it correct; I always make sure to make a backup copy first before editing, just so I have a safe fallback I can use if I foul things up.) Advantage isn't doing maintenance on versions other than the current one as far as their components go, so unless you can upgrade you won't get it from them.

Comment: I would prefer to use FireDAC for this.

Comment: @Victoria: Why? ADS has it's own native controls that are written by the software vendor. They perform better than FireDac (I've tested both ways) and the ADS version just plain works better. The ADS licensing is also much more flexible than the FireDac license requirements for lower SKUs (like Pro).

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the info.  I've been able to rebuild the ADS TDataset packages without errors.  Installing the design bpl, however, is not going well at all, getting the Can't load package c:\users\public\documents\embarcadero\studio\19.0\bpl\adsd10tokyoD.bpl. The specified module could not be found.  I have tried various combinations of setting the path environment variable, as well as the library path and browsing path to make sure the paths are available. If you have any insight on why this won't install, I would really appreciate it.